# I cannot connect to a AWS RDS database by tunnel ssh in pgAdmin

Tags: ssh, amazon-rds, pgadmin, amazon-aurora, vpc

I have a AWS RDS serverless Aurora (with postgres compatibility) cluster attached to an EC2 machine in a VPC.
I set the security group to allow access to port 20 for the ssh tunnel.
If I try to access with pgAdmin by ssh tunnel with my configuration and my identity file I get the error `Unable to connect to server: Failed to create the SSH tunnel. Error Could not establish session to SSH gateway`.

I can access ec2 via ssh and communicate with database from terminal but if I try to access with pgAdmin with the same setup I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

First, the SSH port should be 22, not 20. If you want to use SSH tunneling, you can easily use the following command.

```
ssh -L 6666(your_custom_port):private_ip_address_db:5432 -i yourprivatekey.pem user@ipaddress
```

Log into postgreSQL via command as follows.

```
psql -h localhost:6666
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote wrong about the port, anyway I would like to access via pgAdmin

Answer (score 0):

I received the same message when I try to connect PgAdmin to a db in a VPS ubuntu 20.04. I was able to connects with password, but not with the key.

I solved creating the id_rsa and the id_rsa.pub with this command:

ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096

Then I added the content of id_rsa.pub in the file authorized_keys (.ssh inside the VPS) and load the id_rsa as the identity file (Register- Sever--> shh tunnel tab)

In the newer version of PGAdmin4 it needs to use key in PEM format, not in RFC4716

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).